# Each article post shows a lot of related/featured posts with its excerpt, will this cause any issues with the SEO?

Tags: seo

On each article post, there are at least 3 related posts and 6 featured posts. Each of them contains an excerpt of its own.

It looks something like this
[image]

Each article page will show different related posts (though sometimes will be similar) but will show exactly the same featured posts (with its excerpt).

So in summary, there will be 600-1000 words of content and another 200-350 words of excerpts that will always be the same on each article post.

Will this cause any problems with SEO? 
Does it harder for me to rank? 
Is there a way to work around this, without removing the excerpts?

Answer (score 1):

It could cause... not problems, but a kind of suboptimal setup. Look, your article, which is THE center of the page, is up to 1K words long. Excerpts, same on each article page, are of 20-33% main article length. The excerpts have, as far i see, a kind of higher level headings, like  too. My opinion - the will just thin down the relevancy of the web document, where they appear.

But, on the other side, you want establish good internal linking and give your visitors the possibility to read further. Thats the dilemma. What to do?

I would try to degrade excerpts for Google. For me, the way to go would be to lazy load the excerpts:

- load them later then the main article,
- load them just after visitor scroll down to the end of main article,
- use structured data to markup your main article as main article, and your excerpts as `relatedTo / similarTo`

Comment: Interesting answer. What is this mean "The excerpts have, as far i see, a kind of higher level headings, like too."? I removed all heading tag (h1, h2 etc) from featured and releated posts. Great idea about the lazy load, maybe I can implement it. As for structured data, I just checked, `relatedTo` is used for person, and `similarTo` for product, so I can't use structured data here. But on my HTML tag, I use `aside` for related and featured post section. Also, after checking on SERP, several high ranked site have excerpts on its article too, one of them is Healthline com